# insert last :command into current buffer

Tags: vim, vi

is there any way how i could insert the last command i've entered in commandline mode into the current buffer?

for example, when i try a new mapping i usually type it in like this

```
:nmap * *N
```

in commandline mode.
sometimes i try different mappings for the same problem and play with them a little bit but when i am happy with it and want to insert it in my `.vimrc`.
i always have to type it again (or copy'n'paste it with mouse wich is even worse).
is there any command that can do this for me and just inserts `:nmap * *N` (with or without `:`) in the current buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In insert mode : `<c-r>:`
In normal mode : `":p`

From `:help ":` :

```
":  Contains the most recent executed command-line.  Example: Use
    "@:" to repeat the previous command-line command.
    The command-line is only stored in this register when at least
    one character of it was typed.  Thus it remains unchanged if
    the command was completely from a mapping.
    {not available when compiled without the |+cmdline_hist|
    feature}
```

Comment: Also check out `q:`, which is a great way to play with commands

Comment: @PeterRincker this is awesome, i have no idea that such a thing exists! thanks!